# countdown timer doesn't countdown

Tags: timer, countdown

```
<script>
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 1, 2019 00:00:00").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    document.getElementById("launch").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

   if (distance < 0) {
       clearInterval(x);
       document.getElementById("launch").innerHTML = "EXPIRED"
   }      
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm following a simple tut. & I've gone through it line by line I can't see any mistakes, so I used an html-validator and it spit this out: "Start tag seen without seeing a doctype first. Expected e.g. “<!DOCTYPE html>”.
From line 1, column 1 to line 1, column 8
Code Extract:
<script>↩

    enter code here

Element “head” is missing a required instance of child element “title”.
From line 28, column 5 to line 28, column 13
Code Extract:
↩ </script>" ``

Comment: Hi, I've formatted your code a bit. You should do that yourself next time. Also, please don't add comments, these are for questions from others. [Edit] your question instead. That way you can also format your code (or error messages). Please read [ask], then [edit] your question and make it a [mcve].

Comment: I messed it up when I posted I didn't see an edit button so I had to add my comment after. and thank you